# What are some applications of Surreal Numbers outside of Go endgames?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, surreal-numbers

I've read through Don Knuth's book, a fair amount of "Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays" and watched a handful of videos, and almost all the material seems to talk about *definitions*, like "this is how addition is defined and this is how it correlates to Games", "Games where the second player has a winning strategy correspond to 0" etc.

So far it just seems like fancy notation to me, and I'm having trouble understanding what the point of framing game states as "numbers" is. The only case I can think of/I've been able to find where it's helpful is like in Go endgames, where you can figure out who has a winning strategy when you join/add two Games you already know the "numbers" for.

Especially since dealing with Surreal Numbers means that you can't even discuss all Games (it even fails to describe game states in something simple like Nim)

So, are there any other applications yet?

Comment: "this is how addition is defined and this is how it correlates to Games" I think that is called "connecting semantics to syntax," a key activity in applying mathematics.  That is what one does when framing questions in terms of mathematics that may be able to yield answers.

Comment: I'd probably like to try to answer, but it's a little unclear to me what your question is. Are you asking 1. for more applications like Go endgames, 2. why it is valuable to distinguish surreal numbers from other game values like the value of a heap of size 1 in nim, 3. what people care about/discuss about surreal numbers outside of the context of combinatorial game theory, 4. how it is more than fancy notation for an application like Go endgames, 5. something else I haven't guessed? All of those could get very different long answers.

Comment: @MarkS. The first one (more applications like Go endgames). And for (3), I'm honestly confused on how it's majorly useful even _in_ combinatorial game theory

Answer (score 1):

Surreal numbers are just a subclass of the class of Games that happen to have some very interesting algebraic properties. Conway defined and studied them for these algebraic properties and not for their use in playing games, although he first thought of them in this context. In fact, most partizan games humans play have integers and dyadic fractions but no more surreal values.

If your question was instead about the broader concept of having a number-like system for combinatorial games, including much more than surreal numbers, then it is clear that there are many applications to game analysis, including all impartial games [1] and many partizan games like Domineering [1], Fox-and-Geese [1], Hex [2], Go endgames [3] and even some chess endgames [4].

[1] Berlekamp, Conway, Guy. "Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays"

[2] [Selinger. "On the combinatorial value of Hex positions"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.06694)

[3] Berlekamp, Wolfe. "Mathematical Go: Chilling Gets the Last Point"

[4] [Elkies. "On numbers and endgames: Combinatorial game theory in chess endgames"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9905198)